# DevExpress load large data in extragrid view

Tags: c#

I have to load a large amount of data (30000000) in extragridview using SQL query but I receive an error, [out of memory exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7KWI.png):

Error:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you really expect your users to scroll through 30000000 rows in a grid?  I know I wouldn't want to.  Consider only loading a portion of the data at any one time.

Comment: I would pager that large amount of rows first... @amir malik

Answer (score 0):

The exception that you're experiencing is a result of loading too much data from SQL into a `System.Data.DataTable`.

If you are able to construct a solution that uses "Server Mode". You will be able to pull the data into a Devexpress grid without memory problems.  This method will only pull shown data.

References:

- [GridControl - How to handle large data](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T174401)
- [Data Grid: Binding to Data - Server Mode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398)